# Is it recommended to turn on firewall (via ufw) for Ubuntu run on WSL2 on windows 11?

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I am new to this platform.

I have used a little bit of Ubuntu LTS on WSL2 on a Windows computer.

Recently, I stumbled upon a post suggesting that Linux run on WSL2 will bypass Windows firewall ([source](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/windows-subsystem-for-linux-2-bypasses-the-windows-10-firewall/), from 2020 which is a tad old?).

From googling, I have also learned that WSL2 uses Hyper-V which is "like" a VM on Windows and that an OS inside a VM on Windows will bypass Windows firewall.

From the above, it seems like using Linux on WSL2 without enabling its firewall does not seem like a good security practice.

Question 1: Is it recommended to turn on the firewall specifically for Linux inside WSL2?

Question 2: If so, in Ubuntu LTS, the default setting in ufw of "deny (incoming) allow (outgoing)" sufficient?

I saw that similar questions have been asked before (whether to turn on firewall in Ubuntu) but I have not found one specific to Ubuntu run on WSL2 in Windows. My question pertains to the relationship between WSL2, Hyper-V, and Windows firewall.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Assuming the host machine is connected to a router, the router firewall should suffice.

Comment: `Hyper-V which is "like" a VM` a bit harsh, Hyper-V **is** a Type 1 hypervisor